# How to update UI with validation error message with disabled JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "span8" })
}
```

Model:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpressionAttribute("regex")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

How do I display error message and change css style for a Name text box if javascript is disabled?

As I understood:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, "error text", new { style = "backgroundcolor: red;"})
```

won't work?

In output HTML i can see span generated by `ValidatorMessageFor` but it has a css class `btn-group` that hides this label.

Answer (score 0):

You should add modelstate validation errors from controller and then redisplay the form. It's possible without using javascript

```
ModelState.AddModelError("elementName", "Error definition");
```

Comment: In the model state I do have error. What do you mean by redisplay form ?

Comment: return PartialView("MyView"); You should not redirect, in this case model errors are lost

Comment: I've modified questions by adding controller code. It is what you mean?

Comment: No luck, what I do, I'm going through all error in ModelState and setting flags in Model, by wich I will draw labels with error messages. Feel that this is not a good solution... but it works :(

Comment: Yes, that's bad solution, but I can't find out what's wrong in your code :(

Comment: I'll try with clean solution later and come back if succeed, thx anyway